# Typescript: casting vs interception

Tags: typescript, casting

Some coworkers use different method to convert item in Typescript, and I was curious about which method would be the best or the most conventional.

The case is that we have 2 classes A and B with the same parent, and a list with both types. Then when I pick an item I want to access a specific child attributes.

```
enum Type {
  A = "A",
  B = "B"
}
class Parent {
  type: Type
}
class A extends Parent {
  a: string
}
class B extends Parent {
  b: string
}

array: Parent[] = [...]
```

So option 1 would be to cast the parent after checking the type

```
getSpecificAttribute(item: Parent) {
  let result = null;
  switch(item.type) {
    case Type.A: const child = item as A; result = child.a; break;
    case Type.B: const child = item as B; result = child.b; break;
    default: break;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Option 2 is new to me, using intersection as the parameter type

```
getSpecificAttribute(item: A & B) {
  let result = null;
  switch(item.type) {
    case Type.A: result = item.a; break;
    case Type.B: result = item.b; break;
    default: break;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Or other option ?

Comment: Why not use `instanceof` and if-else-if ?

Comment: it's probably the easiest and of course we didn't thought about it... :(  switch was just here because I think it's cleaner than if-elfe-if when it can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining the `type` property on each class, no assertion is needed:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2FA3gWAFBSgQSgXigCIciAaTbAIQOKvMwF9NMBjAGwEMBnbqABU4AnUABdUlKKwD2IbqKFhWo6UKgAKEZwAms9nCijEwAFyxjASlTMMNtl164owAB6jQ2voJEhx6LFBauiD6hsa08EgAdDgA3JKcZvJCAJYgAObxGJIycgpKKmrqyUkKaelW-tjY3GBIQuqRwDEWWdWGABYp3FGctMltUDZ2GBw8fDSu7iCeAsJiEgFBegZGSBHGUVSDAEalqRmDObLJBaoaJVDJ5ZWSNXXADU1brXed3VE7-QqDwywYADMwCBlClZFB0sBRABlJCsFIAlKsHCiMo7MDuDQpdwQMzeMQWfblKAAHyg4HY7EW2ARWJxUDS8k4IOA0gBuCsIlEYCEIAZON6g1p6mxwGgjNEzNYrPZVE5UJ5fNFEE+gy5ivJYEpWRsQA)

```ts
enum Type {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
}

class Parent {
  constructor (readonly type: Type) {}
}

class A extends Parent {
  readonly type = Type.A;
  a: string;

  constructor (str: string) {
    super(Type.A);
    this.a = str;
  }
}

class B extends Parent {
  readonly type = Type.B;
  b: string;
  
  constructor (str: string) {
    super(Type.B);
    this.b = str;
  }
}

function getSpecificAttribute (item: Parent): string | null {
  if (item instanceof A) return item.a;
  if (item instanceof B) return item.b;
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without a property in parent to hold the type of the child class. The class itself gives this information when checking with `instanceof`.

```
getSpecificAttribute(item: Parent) {
    
   if (item instanceof A)
     return (item as A).a;

   if (item instanceof B)
     return (item as B).b;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following approach (casting without the need for an enum).

BUT I think there is no "best" answer.
You should probably discuss this with your colleagues.
Maybe you could agree on one solution.

```js
function getSpecificAttribute(item: Parent) {
  switch(item.constructor) {
    case A: return (item as A).a;
    case B: return (item as B).b;
    default: return null; // decide what you need
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I totally agree that there's probably no "best" solution and we should definitely agree on a single solution to use everywhere for more coherence. But as we're not a lot I was looking for some other opinions for what could be the most conventional way to do it ;)

Comment: maybe you could mark my answer as your answer ? ;) :D @Luckyn 
As I mentioned, a new solution without the enum. ;)